# rails_xss, prefer raw or .html_escape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

Which is preferable?

```
<%= raw @item.description %>
```

or

```
<%= @item.description.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are outside of view then the `raw` helper is not accessible (you can include it anywhere but by default it is not available in model / controller). So in those cases the `html_safe` is the only sane option.

And inside view? Well, there is source code of the `raw` helper:

```
# actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/raw_output_helper.rb
def raw(stringish)
  stringish.to_s.html_safe
end
```

so there is almost no difference as the `raw` simply calls `#html_safe`

Answer (score 1):

As Radek notes, raw uses html_safe, but because it first casts to a string, it avoids null exceptions. Therefore, raw is slightly better!